# Is the "Accounting" tag wiki accurate?

Tags: support, tags

When I read the following wiki: https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/accounting/info, I am getting mixed messages.

Firstly, it mentions that all accounting questions must be personal.  In my mind a "Personal Accounting" question is simply budgeting (This can be taken with a grain of salt as I am certainly not a money expert).

Secondly, nearly all questions listed under that tag have nothing to do with personal practices, but rather company practices.

Finally, I am unsure why questions that are purely academic (theoretical) are disallowed here.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this tag?

As a side note, the area51 link is no longer valid, and should be removed.

Comment: I removed the dead link from the tag description.

Comment: Bear in mind that *some* **small business** questions are on-topic here, e.g. single self-employed individuals, etc. See [Are small business questions on topic?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-small-business-questions-on-topic) and [Are questions about single-person/family businesses on topic or not?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/are-questions-about-single-person-family-businesses-on-topic-or-not)

Comment: As for theoretical/academic questions, we don't want accounting students to come here and expect they can get their homework questions answered. We have closed *many* of those. Such questions have no bearing on personal finance, is why. Related: [Is double entry accounting a discussable topic here?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/2000/is-double-entry-accounting-a-discussble-topic-here)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I recently learned about variance, and upon further research, found that it is in the field of accounting.  My question is about why certain variance equations are the way they are.  Would that be in scope?

Comment: @NathanMerrill As a theoretical question about accounting having no relationship to personal finance or a sole-owner small business, it would be off topic, even if it is an interesting and valid question to want to ask. Sorry. One day I hope to see an accounting site in the network, but there isn't one yet.