# Why do we have the accounting tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[RonJohn comments](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/113024/reading-the-cash-flow-statement) that its use is a flag that the question is probably off-topic. That sounds like a tag that will not be used by people who know what it's for.

Comment: Do you have an alternative approach, given that there are on-topic account questions?

Comment: It seems to me that the on-topic questions all have at least one other tag which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Probably" <> "definitely".

Discussed already [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/accounting-vs-financial-statement-analysis), [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2066/is-the-accounting-tag-wiki-accurate), and [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2211/why-are-accounting-questions-off-topic-here-even-though-there-are-small-busines).

In a nutshell, there are cases where accounting questions *can* be on-topic, but they are generally not.

Questions at Personal Finance & Money must relate to *personal finance*. And some people do use accounting for their personal finance. So, we need a tag for those instances.

But the mere presence of a tag for 'accounting' doesn't imply *every* accounting question is on-topic — only *some* of them are. Yes, people will misunderstand and ask accounting homework questions anyway, that have zero bearing on their personal finance. That's when the community should vote-to-close.

I wish Stack Exchange had a feature where we could warn somebody that's using the tag on a new question to make really, really sure that their question is appropriate for the site.